# Creating a select list from a database

Tags: c#, html

I am trying to have a select element in my form pull a list of names for the user to choose from, though my prior knowledge doesn't seem correct anymore.

Here's a summarized view of what i'm looking at right now.

```
@{
var productName = Request["ProductName"];
var productSupplierID = Request["SupplierID"];
var productCategoryID = Request["CategoryID"];
var productQuantity = Request["QuantityPerUnit"];
var productUnitPrice = Request["UnitPrice"];

var db = Database.Open("ProfessionalXM_DB");

var supplierQuery = "SELECT SupplierID, CompanyName FROM Suppliers ORDER BY CompanyName";
var categoryQuery = "SELECT CategoryID, CategoryName FROM Categories ORDER BY CategoryName";

var productSupplierName = Request["CompanyName"];
var productCategoryName = Request["CategoryName"];

var supplies = db.Query(supplierQuery, productSupplierID);
var categories = db.Query(categoryQuery);


if (IsPost)
{
    var productsQuery = "INSERT INTO Products (ProductName, SupplierID, CategoryID, QuantityPerUnit, UnitPrice, UnitsInStock,UnitsOnOrder, ReorderLevel, Discontinued) VALUES(@0, @1, @2, @3, @4, 0, 0, 0, 0)";
    try
    {
        db.Execute(productsQuery, productName, productSupplierID, productCategoryID, productQuantity, productUnitPrice);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        <p>Error! @ex.Message</p>
    }
}


<div class="col-md-12">
<form method="post">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="productName" required value="@productName" class="form-control" />

    <label>Supplier</label>
    <select name="productSupplier" required>
        <option>@*Problem lies here*@</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Any solution I can find online is in javascript or something else which unfortunately not allowed in this case.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: So what's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to a solution conforming to your current style of code then all you need to do is get a list of suppliers and write a loop to create the select list. You can try something like this:

```
//Assuming that all the suppliers are stored in a list called suppliersList
var suppliersList = //write a query to get all the suppliers (Name and Code)

//In you HTML form, loop over all the supplier records in the suppliers list:
<select name="productSupplier" required>
@foreach (var supplier in suppliersList) {
     <option value='@supplier.Code'>@supplier.Name</option>
}
</select>
```

Hope this helps!